# Selenium Tooltip Mouseover not working

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium

I have a bootstrap tooltip adding by jquery by validation. I need to test it on Selenium(Tooltip it self not poping-up by Selenium). I tried all the ways but no luck.

I'm Using Firefox 51v. and Maven version:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.53.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

HTML code:

```
<input id="ele-id" class="text-right red-tooltip" maxlength="10" ng-change="validateFun()" data-original-title="" title="" type="text">
```

In Javascript:

```
$('#ele-id').tooltip({title: 'Must be between 0 and 1', placement: 'right'});
```

and My Java Test Code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ele-id"));
String initialVal = element.getAttribute("value");
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("-1");
//element.click();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
//action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
action.clickAndHold(element).perform();
//JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebElement toolTipElement = driver.findElement(By.className("tooltip"));
String toolTipText = toolTipElement.getText();
Assert.assertEquals("Must be between 0 and 1", toolTipText);
```

I Apologies for more code I'm pasting here, commented code also i tried.

Comment: so the tool tip appears when you click on the element or when you just hover you mouse, like tags on stackoverflow site.

Comment: @GaurangShah - Yes tooltip is coming when i mouse over the textbox manually. while testing time manually I bring it up test case is success.

Comment: my question is, do you need a click or mouse hover for tooltip?

Comment: mouse hover will be better.

Comment: then can you try mouse however rather than click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did unfocus and again focus the element so that I can able to read the Tooltip.

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('ITEM_SMOOTHING_DEFAULT-value').blur();");
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('ITEM_SMOOTHING_DEFAULT-value').focus();");
WebElement toolTipElement = driver.findElement(By.className("tooltip"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mouse hover event

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST /session/fca599f1-d041-4eb3-b532-4fe8ce7968b8/moveto did not match a known command

Comment: @Rajesh there is an issue in webdriver, however it's for geckodriver.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3287